# To do list with array and functions

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to create a to-do list with an array, functions and js must be separated from HTML. The HTML part is fine, but I have troubles finishing the functions.
Also the EventListener works.

---

```
<form id="todoForm">
  <input id="todoInput" type="text">
  <button type="button" id="button">Add your To Do</button> 
</form>
<ol id="toDoList"></ol>
```

We have the array 'todos', the button click is noticed, and the function 'addTodo' is called, which (I hope so) pushes the input into the array.
I don't know how to call next function, which should create the array items as li elements, that is the place where I need help. The content in function 'printTodos' is garbage.

```
 var todos = [];

    document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function 
    addTodo () {
    todos.push('input')  

    function printTodos () {
        var item = document.createElement("li");
        var node = createTextNode(input);
        // I am stuck 
    }
  });
```

Comment: Please note the description of the todo tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close, except you do not want to create the `addTodo` and `printTodos` function inside your `click` event listener.

What you can instead do is define the two functions outside of it, and call them inside your click event listener, like so:

```
var todos = [];

function addTodo() {
    var inputValue = document.getElementById('todoInput').value;
    todos.push(inputValue);
}

function printTodos() {
    var list = document.getElementById('toDoList');
    list.innerHTML = ''; //Reset the list content whenever we print the todos, so we don't end up with duplicate todo items.

    for (var i = 0; i < todos.length; i++) {
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        var listItem = li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(todos[i]));
        list.appendChild(listItem);
    }
}

document.getElementById('click', function() {
    addTodo();
    printTodos();
});
```

What we do here is, in the `addTodo` function, we programmatically get the text typed into the `todoInput` and add it to the array. Then, in the `printTodos` function, we loop over all the entered todos and create `<li>` element filled with the todo text. At the end, we append the new list item to the `toDosList`.

Answer (score 2):

I've made a fully working code pen example for you. Please take a look on it or go with the above answer. Here is what you need https://codepen.io/waleedbinkhalid/pen/aRvwmo

```
 var todos = [];
    document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function () {
 var list = $('#toDoList'); 
      var todoInput = $('#todoInput').val();
    todos.push(todoInput)  

        var item = document.createElement("li");
        for (var i = 0; i < todos.length; i++) {
        var listItem = $(document.createTextNode(todos[i]));
        list.append(document.createTextNode(todos[i]));
    }
  });
`
```

Comment: Thank you but are you using jQuerry? I have no idea about jQuerry and would like do js only for now. Can you "translate" it into js, is it even possible or must be jQ code completely rewritten in js?

Comment: I've re-code it for you please and now it is now totally in pure javascript no use of jquery please take a look at the code pen example. https://codepen.io/waleedbinkhalid/pen/aRvwmo